# Grassmannian $Gr_{\mathbb{R}}(r, n)$ and $Gr_{\mathbb{C}}(r, n)$ as homogeneous space?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, quotient-spaces, grassmannian, homogeneous-spaces

It is known that Grassmannian as a homogeneous space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian#The_Grassmannian_as_a_homogeneous_space
gives that:
$$
{{Gr_{\mathbb{R}}(r, n) {{=}} O(n)/(O(r) \times O(n − r))}}.
$$
If the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and $GL(V)$ is considered as a Lie group, then this construction makes the Grassmannian into a smooth manifold. It also becomes possible to use other groups to make this construction. To do this, fix an inner product on $V$. Over $\mathbb{R}$, one replaces $GL(V)$ by the orthogonal group $O(V)$, and by restricting to orthonormal frames, one gets the relation above.

My questions are that:

1. do we have:
   $$
   {{Gr_{\mathbb{C}}(r, n) {{=}} U(n)/(U(r) \times U(n − r))}}?
   $$

2. What are some good refs on studying the topological (e.g., cohomology) and geometrical properties of these spaces: $Gr_{\mathbb{R}}(r, n)$ and $Gr_{\mathbb{C}}(r, n)$?

Comment: 1. Yes. Same proof as in the real case. For 2., complete flags yield CW-decompositions of ${\rm Gr}_k(V)$, [this might be helpful](https://math.berkeley.edu/~hutching/teach/215b-2005/blasiak.pdf).